# Python : IF ELSE both getting executed

Tags: python, json, if-statement, unicode, utf-8

I am extracting a JSON response and storing its data into a python list. Some of the fields in response is in 'unicode' format so I am converting it into 'utf-8' format before storing it into list. Now the problem is, some unicode fields are returning 'NoneType' which can not be encoded OR operated in any case. So I have written an IF ELSE block checking first whether it is 'None' or not. But I assume it is not working as expected. Below is my code :

```
res = []
for a in response['Data'] : 

    res.append(a ['Id']['Id']) #ParticipatingIndividualId
    res.append(a ['UserId']) #UserId
    res.append(a ['DisplayName']) # FirstName_EN

    if (a ['Company']['en']) is None :
        res.append(None)
    else :
        res.append(a ['Company']['en']).encode('utf-8') #ParticipatingCompanyName_EN
...
...
```

But after running this, it still gives me an error saying "NoneType object has no attribute encode". So I guess my IF ELSE logic is not working. OR there might be some other issue as well. Can anyone suggest what is the problem here. It would be a great help.

Comment: You put the encode function onto append function

Comment: thanks @cricket_007, but is there any syntactical error in it? If yes can you tell me the right one ? And I also tried storing the field into a variable and apply encode function to that variable. e.g  var = a ['Company']['en'] var.encode('utf-8')

Comment: Yes, there's a syntax error... Append returns None. Check your parentheses. You do not need an intermediate variable

Comment: Sorry but I am not understanding your point. Can you please elaborate. Sorry I am a beginner in python

Comment: Rewrite the entire line... There is a period after `append(a ['Company']['en'])`. You're not encoding  the actual string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If and else are not running at the same time. That's never possible

You need to encode the string, not the append function

`a['Company']['en'].encode('utf-8')`

You can also do this all in one line

```
res.append(None if a['Company']['en']) is None else a['Company']['en'].encode('utf-8'))
```